# Как использовать статическую библиотеку?

Tags: c, lib, library

Есть проект на C, и имеется статическая библиотека (.lib), как теперь подключить эту библиотеку к объектному коду моего проекта (для создания объектного кода моего проекта я использую следующую конструкцию: gcc -c somefile.c). Я пробовал использовать #pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib") но такой способ не прошёл, при компиляции я получаю сообщения вроде: undefined reference to 'funcname'. Ещё я пробовал сначала создать somefile.o, а потом при помощи линковщика (ld) связать их так: ld somefile.o libname.lib. Вопрос, как правильно подключать статические библиотеки к объектному коду, и как эти библиотеки лучше всего компилировать (я использую cl.exe, потому что с gcc у меня не получается).

Примечания: gcc v8.2.0 ОС Win 8 x86 (хотя компилятор и ОС скорее всего не имеют значения).

Comment: Если кратко и судя по описанному - никак. У `gcc` и `cl` разные ABI (грубо говоря, формат бинарных файлов) и прицепить библиотеку от VS к gcc 8.2 не сможете. Нужно собрать библиотеку той же версией (с той же разрядностью) `gcc`. И потом, можно будет использовать параметр `-l` (буква 'эль') для библиотеки при сборке, типа: `gcc file.c -lname`, где `name` - краткое имя библиотеки, а полное имя тогда будет вида `libname.a`.

Comment: Вроде бы mingw может линковаться и нормально работать с чисто сишными `.lib`, но нужно проверять. Еще, если не секрет, где вы нашли gcc 8.2 для windows?

Comment: Дико извиняюсь за ошибку, я имел ввиду MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишем код библиотеки

example.h

```
int add(int, int);
```

example.c

```
int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Компилируем

```
gcc -c example.c
```

Упаковываем

```
ar rc libexample.a example.o
```

Поздравляю, у вас есть статическая библиотека. Попробуем её использовать.

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "example.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int x = add(3, 5);  // Библиотечный вызов
  printf("3 + 5 = %d\n", x);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Компилируем

```
gcc -L. -I. -o test.exe test.c -lexample
```

Ещё раз поздравляю, у вас есть исполняемый файл статически слинкованный с библиотекой.

Естественно, пример по максимуму упрощён.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Но ещё маленький вопрос, чем отличаются libname.a и libname.lib?

Comment: Форматом. Первое - это библиотеки характерные для nix-систем, вторые - для Windows.

Comment: Спасибо, и ещё кое-что, насколько мне известно, статические библиотеки  содержат уже откомпилированные функции. Из чего следует что такие библиотеки не переносимы с платформы на платформу. Это так?

Comment: Библиотеку скомпилированную в Windows вы не сможете использовать в Linux и наоборот. Так же как и с исполняемыми файлами.